# How Can The Name of the Selected Option of an Option Set be Retrieved with JavaScript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How can the name, rather than the value, be retrieved from a field with the CRM JavaScript SDK?
The value can be retrieved with the SDK:

```javascript
SDK.REST.retrieveRecord(...);
    account.completePopulateAccountFields = function (account) {
    var type = account["optionsetname"].Value;
    if (type != null)
        //perform action
```

Only the value is returned in this call.
Is there an Option Set Set in OrganizationData.svc that can be queried with the retrieved value?

Comment: See my comment to the replier about the source code. It looks so much nicer when colorified. (Technically the same contents but sooo easier to read, hehe.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the same named option set to Contact and made it read only, populating it with the value that I get from the Parent Account. 
The requirement was to show the Parent Account Type on Contact
I still do not know how to get the name of the option set value with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it looks like it will work, but I have not tried it.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use metadataservice to retrieve the label name. Check the code for this:

C#:

```csharp
RetrieveAttributeRequest request = new RetrieveAttributeRequest {
   EntityLogicalName = entityName,
   LogicalName = attributeName,
   RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
};

RetrieveAttributeResponse response = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)service.Execute(request);

PicklistAttributeMetadata metadata = (PicklistAttributeMetadata)response.AttributeMetadata;

OptionMetadata[] optionList = metadata.OptionSet.Options.ToArray();

foreach (OptionMetadata option in optionList) {
    //option.Value - Value of option
    //option.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label - Label name of that value
}
```

If you want know a label text where you just know the value and you are not in form use this in [Javascript](http://mahenderpal.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/get-optionset-label-based-on-optionset-value-using-javascript/).

If you are in the form where you want obtain the text of a option set you can simple do that:

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("optionsetfieldname").getText();
```

Comment: @PedroAzevedo Don't forget to mark the syntax for nicer code display. If there's no language specification in the tags, SO gets confused. I updated your post. Take a look. :)

Comment: Thanks Konrad i beginning and this advice's are very useful.

Comment: @Pedro Thank you for the update. I am not in the form. I am retrieving the option set value from the Parent Account of a Contact with SDK.retrieveRecord().

Comment: @Bvrce use the link of my post for do that

Answer (score 0):

Something changed in CRM recently(?) as a result of which calling Xrm.Page.getAttribute("optionsetfieldname").getText() directly gives you an error.
Use a two step approach:

```
var sOptionsetAttribute = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("optionsetfieldname");
var sOptionsetValueName = sOptionsetAttribute.getText();
```